# Div over another with animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the example I used div, but I need to have a picture like slide from right to left and then from left to right, but I can not,is that they do not the animation on top of another ...

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="background">1</div>
    <div id="logo">2</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#background").animate({
    marginLeft: "500px",
}, 1000);
$("#logo").animate({
    marginRight: "500px",
}, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kvRA/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7kvRA/

Comment: "In the example" What example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `#logo` div's top margin to negative the `#background` div's height in the css or whatever is required

```
margin-top:-150px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fEPsX/

Comment: Thanks for the trouble wirey!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what answer you're looking for, but:

If you're looking at reversing the animation once it finishes, try adding an onComplete to your jQuery animate method.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/  (Look up the documentation for 'complete')

If you're looking to animate a div on top of another div, use `absolute` positioning and `z-index`ing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to put one over the other, if I use absolute position the animation does not work

Comment: The animation would work if you had them positioned absolutely, and  tweened the `left` property as opposed to the `marginLeft` one. Either way would work fine. I often find animating using `absolute` values is more precise. Glad you solved your problem.